# Varray data type is not getting mapped with .net core entity using Devart oracle dot connect 9

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, devart, varray

I am trying to fetch data from a table(oracle db 12c) using Devart EFCore 9.8 and Oracle dot connect trial license in MSEFCore 2.2.4. But the VARRAY column is not getting mapped. It's throwing an exception -

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'TierInfoTemp.num_arr'
 is of type 'OracleType' which is not supported by current database 
provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property
 using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.
Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

My DBContext.cs:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TierInfoTemp>(entity =>
            {
                OracleConnectionStringBuilder oraCSB = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
                oraCSB.Direct = true;
                oraCSB.Server = "xxx";
                oraCSB.Port = xxxx;
                oraCSB.Sid = "xxxx";
                oraCSB.UserId = "xxxx";
                oraCSB.Password = "xxx";
                entity.Property(e => e.num_arr).HasColumnType("VARRAY")
                .HasConversion<OracleType>();
            });
        }
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<TierInfoTemp> tier_info_temp { get; set; }
```

Entity:

```
public class TierInfoTemp
    {
        [Column("TIER_ID")]
        [Key]
        public int tier_id { get; set; }
        [Column("TIER_NAME")]
        public string tier_name { get; set; }
        [Column("IS_ACTIVE")]
        public int is_active { get; set; }
        [Column("REGION_ID")]
        public int region_id { get; set; }
        [Column("NUM_ARR")]
        public OracleType num_arr { get; set; }  ///VARARY Field
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Please comment if required further details.

Answer (score 0):

The list of Oracle data types supported by Devart EF Core provider is available at https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?DataTypeMapping.html.

OracleType is currently not supported via EF Core, but you can work with it via plain ADO.NET: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Varray.html.